# How to get the id/name of the container in which my web application is running to serve the current user request

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-health-check, kubernetes-ingress

We are using Dockers and Kubernetes to containerize my .Net web application and scale up to 8-9 replicas. So we installed Dockers (in my Win 10 machine) and used Linux containers.

Orchestration is done by Kubernetes. I would like to get the name/id of the container in which my web application is running to serve the current user request.

Could not find a way to get the id/name of the container from my .Net Web application. Please share me your thoughts on this.

Regards

Comment: Have you tried calling `System.Environment.MachineName` within the code? It should return the container id in which the dotnet code runs.

Answer (score 2):

You can expose Pod fields as environment variables, the field `metadata.name` will contain the name of the Pod.

Documentation and example: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#use-container-fields-as-values-for-environment-variables

Edit:
You can also use `System.Environment.MachineName` as @vahdet commented earlier. The hostname of the container is the pod id.